# ViSEAGO - Genes of interest: "background" and "selection" file input

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm trying to use ViSEAGO for the GO visualization in Solanum lycopersicum for differentially methylated genes (DMG).

According to the ViSEAGO guide, two files are needed as inputs: "background" and "selection"

ViSEAGO Gene of interest input:

[image]

But there is no description about the type of file, tabulation, data contents etc...

Does anyone know what is the correct file format for "background" and "selection" input?

- For the "background" I used the Solanum lycopersicum Gene sets from EnsemblPlants in gff3 format (https://plants.ensembl.org/info/data/ftp/index.html).
- For the "selection" I used a list of DMG ID (es. Solyc12g345678.1.1) in a simple txt file

[image]

After loading this file and the GO annotation (myGENE2GO) from EnsemblPlants, when I run the following code (from ViSEAGO guide):

```
# create topGOdata for BP
BP<-ViSEAGO::create_topGOdata(
 geneSel=selection,
 allGenes=background,
 gene2GO=myGENE2GO, 
 ont="BP",
 nodeSize=5
 )
```

I obtain an error:

```
allGenes contain genes redondancy.
duplicate elements were removed.
geneSel contain genes redondancy.
duplicate elements were removed.
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : allGenes must be a factor with 2 levels
```

Anyone knows why I obtain this error?